# ExtJS4.2 carousel not working with ExtJS5

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs5

I have a requirement to use carousel in one of my project. Recently we migrated from ExtJS4.2.1 to ExtJS5 The example shown [here](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/community/carouselcontainer/) is working absolutely fine with ExtJS4.2.1 but when I use it with ExtJS5 it gives the error: "Ext.util.Observable#addEvents" is deprecated."

Can someone update the code or point out the error? Here is the code:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.define('carouselContainer', {
        extend: 'Ext.container.Container'
        , alias: 'widget.carousel'

        , layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
            , align: 'stretch'
        }
        , defaults: { flex: 1 }
        , style: {
            background: 'url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kanvyoXSOSs/Tsi0W496bzI/AAAAAAAAAG8/-Bq53wJqaqM/s320/carbonfibre.png)'
        }

        , initComponent: function () {
            var me = this;

            me.addEvents('carouselchange');

            me.callParent(arguments);
        }
        , onDocMouseup: function () {
            var me = this;
            me.drag = false;
            var children = me.items.items;
            var parentLeft = me.ownerCt.el.getLeft();
            var rule = 1000000;
            var target;
            Ext.each(children, function (div, i) {
                l = Math.abs(div.el.getLeft() - parentLeft);
                if (l < rule) {
                    rule = l;
                    target = div;
                };
            });
            me.showChild(target);
        }
        , onMousedown: function (e) {
            e.stopEvent();    // prevents selecting the underlying text and whatnot
            var me = this;
            me.drag = true;
            me.startX = e.getX();
            var par = me.el.first();
            par.on({
                mousemove: function (e) {
                    e.stopEvent();    // prevents selecting the underlying text and whatnot
                    if (me.drag) {
                        var rate = 1;
                        if (par.getLeft() > me.ownerCt.el.getLeft() || par.getRight() < me.ownerCt.el.getRight()) {
                            rate = 2;
                        }
                        par.move('l', (me.startX - e.getX()) / rate, false);
                        me.startX = e.getX();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        , syncSizeToOwner: function () {
            var me = this;
            if (me.ownerCt) {
                me.setSize(me.ownerCt.el.getWidth() * me.items.items.length, me.ownerCt.el.getHeight());
            }
        }
        , showChild: function (item) {
            var me = this
                , left = item.el.getLeft() - me.el.getLeft();
            me.el.first().move('l', left, true);
            me.currentItem = item;
            me.fireEvent('carouselchange', me, item);
        }
        , nextChild: function () {
            var me = this;
            var next = me.currentItem.nextSibling();
            me.showChild(next || me.items.items[0]);
        }
        , previousChild: function () {
            var me = this;
            var next = me.currentItem.previousSibling();
            me.showChild(next || me.items.items[me.items.items.length - 1]);
        }
        , onRender: function () {
            var me = this;

            me.currentItem = me.items.items[0];

            if (me.ownerCt) {
                me.relayEvents(me.ownerCt, ['resize'], 'owner');
                me.on({
                    ownerresize: me.syncSizeToOwner
                });
            }

            me.mon(Ext.getBody(), 'mouseup', me.onDocMouseup, me);
            me.mon(Ext.fly(me.el.dom), 'mousedown', me.onMousedown, me);

            me.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });

    Ext.define('carouselTb', {
        extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar'
        , alias: 'widget.carouseltb'

        , directionals: true

        , initComponent: function () {
            var me = this;

            me.items = [{
                xtype: 'tbfill'
            }, {
                xtype: 'tbfill'
            }]

            me.callParent(arguments);
        }
        , handleCarouselEvents: function (carousel) {
            var me = this;
            me.relayEvents(carousel, ['carouselchange']);
            me.on('carouselchange', me.onCarouselChange, me, {buffer: 20});
        }
        , onCarouselChange: function (carousel, item) {
            var me = this;
            console.log(me);
            var navSprites = me.down('draw').surface.getGroup('carousel');
            navSprites.setAttributes({opacity: 0.2}, true);
            var i = carousel.items.indexOf(item);
            navSprites.each(function (s) {
                if (s.index == i) {
                    s.animate({
                        to: {
                            opacity: 0.7
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        , onRender: function () {
            var me = this;

            var prev = {
                text: '<'
                , handler: function () {
                    me.ownerCt.down('carousel').previousChild();
                }
            };

            var next = {
                text: '>'
                , handler: function () {
                    me.ownerCt.down('carousel').nextChild();
                }
            };

            Ext.suspendLayouts(); 
            if (me.directionals) {
                me.insert(0, prev);
                me.insert(me.items.items.length, next);
            }

            var index = me.items.indexOf(me.down('tbfill'));
            var circles = [];
            var x = 0;
            var i = 0;
            Ext.each(me.ownerCt.down('carousel').items.items, function (item) {
                var config = {
                    type: 'circle'
                    , x: x
                    , y: 0
                    , index: i
                    , radius: 1
                    , fill: 'black'
                , opacity: i == 0 ? 0.7 : 0.2
                    , group: 'carousel'
                }
                circles.push(config);
                x += 3;
                i++;
            });
            me.insert(index + 1, {
                xtype: 'draw'
                , height: 12
                , items: circles
            });

            Ext.resumeLayouts();

            Ext.defer(function () {
                var c = me.down('draw').surface.getGroup('carousel');
                c.each(function (s) {
                    s.on({
                        click: function (s) {
                            c.setAttributes({opacity: 0.2}, true);
                            var carousel = me.ownerCt.down('carousel');
                            carousel.showChild(carousel.items.items[s.index]);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }, 2);

            var carousel = me.ownerCt.down('carousel');
            if (carousel) {
                me.handleCarouselEvents(carousel);
            }

            me.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });

    Ext.widget('viewport', {
        layout: 'fit'
        , items: [{
            xtype: 'panel'
            , items: [{
                xtype: 'carousel'
                , items: [{
                    xtype: 'panel'
                    , title: '1'
                    , html: 'testing'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel'
                    , title: '2'
                    , columns: [{
                        text: 'Label'
                        , dataIndex: 'label'       
                    }]
                    , store: {
                        fields: ['label']
                        , data: [{
                            label: 'a'
                        }, {
                            label: 'b'
                        }, {
                            label: 'c'
                        }, {
                            label: 'd'
                        }, {
                            label: 'e'
                        }, {
                            label: 'f'
                        }, {
                            label: 'g'
                        }, {
                            label: 'h'
                        }, {
                            label: 'i'
                        }, {
                            label: 'j'
                        }, {
                            label: 'k'
                        }, {
                            label: 'l'
                        }, {
                            label: 'm'
                        }, {
                            label: 'n'
                        }, {
                            label: 'o'
                        }, {
                            label: 'p'
                        }, {
                            label: 'q'
                        }, {
                            label: 'r'
                        }, {
                            label: 's'
                        }, {
                            label: 't'
                        }, {
                            label: 'u'
                        }, {
                            label: 'v'
                        }, {
                            label: 'w'
                        }, {
                            label: 'x'
                        }, {
                            label: 'y'
                        }, {
                            label: 'z'   
                        }, {
                            label: 'a'
                        }, {
                            label: 'b'
                        }, {
                            label: 'c'
                        }, {
                            label: 'd'
                        }, {
                            label: 'e'
                        }, {
                            label: 'f'
                        }, {
                            label: 'g'
                        }, {
                            label: 'h'
                        }, {
                            label: 'i'
                        }, {
                            label: 'j'
                        }, {
                            label: 'k'
                        }, {
                            label: 'l'
                        }, {
                            label: 'm'
                        }, {
                            label: 'n'
                        }, {
                            label: 'o'
                        }, {
                            label: 'p'
                        }, {
                            label: 'q'
                        }, {
                            label: 'r'
                        }, {
                            label: 's'
                        }, {
                            label: 't'
                        }, {
                            label: 'u'
                        }, {
                            label: 'v'
                        }, {
                            label: 'w'
                        }, {
                            label: 'x'
                        }, {
                            label: 'y'
                        }, {
                            label: 'z'
                        }]
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'panel'
                    , title: '3'
                    , html: 'One last panel'
                }]
            }]
            , dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'carouseltb'
                , dock: 'top'        
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
        me.addEvents('carouselchange');
```

`addEvents` has been deprecated in Ext JS 5.0 and will raise an error when used. Don't use it.

Comment: It's also no longer needed. From the documentation: `@deprecated 2.0 It's no longer needed to add events before firing.`